# Why if I var_dump($view) in a Symfony2 PHP template, the page crashes?

Tags: php, symfony, templating

I have started learning Symfony2, I am reading the book.

I was curious to see which instance is stored inside the $view variable avaiable as a helper var inside a Symfony template, so I made this template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>PHP Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    Number: <strong><?= $number; ?></strong>
    <?php var_dump($view); exit;?>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I execute the page the browser stucks and looking at the Activity Monitor I see a "Google Chrome Helper" that exhaust the CPU... Why all this happens?

Thanks for the attention!

EDIT: this is part of the initial output:

```
 object(Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TimedPhpEngine)#311 (14) { 
    ["stopwatch":protected]=> object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch)#204 (2) { 
    ["sections":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch":private]=> array(1) { ["__root__"]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Section)#203 (4) { 
["events":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Section":private]=> array(1) { ["__section__.child"]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent)#107 (4) { 
["periods":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(0) { } ["origin":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> float(1.41716199817E+12) 
["category":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> string(7) "section" 
["started":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> float(0) }}} 
["origin":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Section":private]=> NULL 
["id":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Section":private]=> NULL 
["children":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Section":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Section)#106 (4) { 
["events":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Section":private]=> array(25) { ["__section__"]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent)#105 (4) { 
["periods":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(0) { } 
["origin":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> float(1.41716199817E+12) 
["category":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> string(7) "default" 
["started":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> float(0.1)}} 
["kernel.request"]=> object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent)#104 (4) { 
["periods":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod)#75 (3) { 
["start":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(0) 
["end":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(84) 
["memory":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(6553600) } } 
["origin":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> float(1.41716199817E+12) 
["category":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> string(7) "section" 
["started":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(0) { } } 
["Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener"]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent)#103 (4) { 
["periods":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(3) { [0]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod)#102 (3) { 
["start":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(0) 
["end":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(10) 
["memory":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(6291456) } [1]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod)#101 (3) { 
["start":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(10) 
["end":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(10) 
["memory":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(6291456) } [2]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod)#100 (3) { 
["start":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(10) 
["end":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(10) 
["memory":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(6291456) } } 
["origin":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> float(1.41716199817E+12) 
["category":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> string(14) "event_listener" 
["started":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(0) { } } 
["Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener"]=> 
object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent)#99 (4) { 
["periods":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod)#98 (3) { ["start":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(10) ["end":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(10) ["memory":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchPeriod":private]=> int(6291456) } } ["origin":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> float(1.41716199817E+12) ["category":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> string(14) "event_listener" ["started":"Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\StopwatchEvent":private]=> array(0) { } } ["Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\Profile
```

Please correct me cause I am only supposing:
This PHP template engine (as I saw from the docs) times the time spent to render a template while it renders it, and the Stopwatch component handles this behaviour internally, so as the Template engine will stop timing the rendering only when actually the template finishes, but paradoxically it won't finish because the Template engine will be modified over and over while the template renders, thus the infinite loop, am I right?

Comment: Use a debugger like XDebug instead of dumping tons of information to the page. There's probably a large hierarchy of objects being dumped and your browser is trying to render loads of textual object representations.

Comment: Regarding your edit:
I think the stopwatch is for the symfony2 debug toolbar and I don't think the problem lies there. You just shouldn't use print_r() or var_dump() in php when you have entities with bi-directional relations, because those commands are to primitive to detect the recursion.

Comment: All right, understood!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the View has a relation to another object which reflects back to the View and results in a recursion.

Usually in symfony you can use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($view)` but I'm not sure if it is available in PHP-Templates.

Id advise you to try twig templates, they're awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Install Xdebug:
http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Or try this:
https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the new Symfony var-dumper: https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper

**Add to your composer.json**:

```
"require-dev": {
    ...,
    "symfony/var-dumper": "@dev"
}
```

**Usage:** dump($var);